# Kotlin list on editing a item after adding the changes are replicated in added list

Tags: list, kotlin, arraylist

I have created a data class and added into list, same item is added multiple times in a list, if I change a value of the item and it is replicated in the items that are added in a list.

```
data class Boy(var name : String, var age : Int)

    fun main() {
        var boysList = arrayListOf<Boy>()
        var boysListFinal = arrayListOf<Boy>()
        val boy1 = Boy("test1234",1)
        boysList.add(boy1)
        for(boy in boysList){
            boysListFinal.add(boy)
            boysListFinal.add(boy)
            boysListFinal.add(boy)
            boy.name = "test1"
            boysListFinal.add(boy)
        }
        println(boysListFinal)
    }
```

Output

```
[Boy(name=test1, age=1), Boy(name=test1, age=1), Boy(name=test1, age=1), Boy(name=test1, age=1)]
```

Expected output

```
[Boy(name=test1234, age=1), Boy(name=test1234, age=1), Boy(name=test1234, age=1), Boy(name=test1, age=1)]
```

I have tried by assigning the item to a object still I cannot get the expected output

```
fun main() {
    var boysList = arrayListOf<Boy>()
    var boysListFinal = arrayListOf<Boy>()
    val boy1 = Boy("test1234",1)
    boysList.add(boy1)
    for(boy in boysList){
        boysListFinal.add(boy)
        boysListFinal.add(boy)
        boysListFinal.add(boy)        
        val boy2 = boy
        boy2.name = "test1"
        boysListFinal.add(boy2)
    }
    println(boysListFinal)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you put the same item several times into the list, all changes to that item will be visible on all occurrences in the list, because it is always pointing to that same item.

The declaration of variable `boy2` does not produce another `Boy`, but it is only another reference to the same `boy`.

You can use the [copy function of data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying) to produce a copy of your object:

```
val boy2 = boy.copy(name = "test1")
boysListFinal.add(boy2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour.

The important thing to note is that you are only creating one instance of the `Boy` class, because you call the constructor `Boy(...)` only once. You're never making any copies of it either (which you could do using the `copy(..)` method that was generated for the `Boy` class because it's a `data class`).

So there is effectively only one `Boy` in the whole program. When you assign that instance to variables, or when you add it to a list, you're only setting a reference to that same object, so you have many different places that "point to" the same object in memory. If you mutate a property of that object, any place that references the object will see the change.